How to migrate a website to another hosting provider without affecting the GoDaddy email service?
I developed a new website for my client and want to upload it to my Hostinger hosting. The current website and email service he uses are with GoDaddy.
I want to keep his email with GoDaddy and direct the DNS of the website to my server.
I tried doing this by accessing the DNS zone and changing the IP of the A record, but my client's email went down.
I found out that the email is accessed at webmail.sombraeucalipto.com.br. So, I need to find a new way to make this migration. Can you help me?
